# How to increase a date within a loop in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm working on this function that basically works on 2 dates.
One is the current date, the other is a 1 month ago date.
Heres the code:

```
 dateTale=$(date -d "$(date) - 1 month" +%Y%m%d)
 now=$(date +%Y%m%d)
 while ["$dateTale" -lt "$now"]
  do 
   $dateTale=$(date -d "$dateTale + 1 day" +%Y%m%d) 
  echo "adding" 
 done
```

As you can see i'm trying to increase dateTale until it reaches the current date, buit i keep on getting the error message: [20120703: command not found
I tried removing the quotes from within the while statement but still same error message.
But even when resolved, will -lt calculate the actual date value or the numeric one?

Any advice?

Comment: It's easier for us to help you if you copy the *exact* error message rather than summarizing it.

Comment: `-lt` will compare the two values as strings. Given the format you use, the string order is also the correct date order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spaces are important when using the `[` command:

```
while [ "$dateTale" -lt "$now" ]
```

Also, you don't use the '$' when assigning to variables (unlike perl or php):

```
dateTale=$(date -d "$dateTale + 1 day" +%Y%m%d)
```

Comment: This is a problem with the posted code, but doesn't solve the problem in the question.

Comment: Right, I didn't even read that far before seeing the other answer.

Comment: Also, as far as other problems, he has a `$` on the left side of an assignment.

Comment: It was the white space in the while statement thank you! but also the '$' in dateTale=$(date -d "$dateTale + 1 day" +%Y%m%d)  but i though that by using $dateTale we actually increase the existing variable while using dateTale + 1 day we create a new variable containing the current date + 1 day, ending up in an infinite loop, to my surprise, is completelly the other way around

Answer (score 2):

Should be `$dateTale` not `$(dateTale)`.

Comment: while ["$dateTale" -lt "$now"]; do $dateTale=$(date -d "$dateTale + 1 day" +%Y%m%d); echo "adding"; done still not working

Comment: Please edit your question and add in the *exact* error message. "Still not working" does not communicate much of use.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

dateTale=$(date -d "$(date) - 1 month" +%Y%m%d)
now=$(date +%Y%m%d)


 while [ $dateTale -lt $now ]
  do
   dateTale=$(date -d "$dateTale + 1 day" +%Y%m%d)
  echo $dateTale
 done
```

Comment: `#!/bin/sh

dateTale=$(date -d "$(date) - 1 month" +%Y%m%d)
now=$(date +%Y%m%d)


 while [ $dateTale -lt $now ]
  do
   dateTale=$(date -d "$dateTale + 1 day" +%Y%m%d)
  echo $dateTale
 done
`

Comment: while you may have solved the problem, it's helpful to explain what mistake was made in the original code.