# Bash for loop for sequence of dates in calendar

Tags: bash, date

I want to run through a for loop starting from start_date to end_date as per calendar.  The format is like this:  `YYYYMMDD`

eg:  start_date: `20140226` , end_date: `20140303` should print `20140226, 20140227, 20140228, 20140301, 20140302, 20140303`.
Thanks!

Comment: Quite similar to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797805/how-to-increase-a-date-within-a-loop-in-bash

Comment: Which version of `date`? GNU `date` and BSD `date` accept quite different options. (I ask because a solution will likely use that program.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
#!/bin/bash

start=$(date -d "$1" '+%Y%m%d' 2>/dev/null)
end=$(date -d "$2" '+%Y%m%d' 2>/dev/null)

[[ $start != "" && $end != "" ]] || exit 0
[[ $(date -d "$start" +%s) -le $(date -d "$end" +%s) ]] || exit 0

while :; do
  echo "$start"
  [[ $start -eq $end ]] && exit 0
  start=$(date -d "$start +1days" '+%Y%m%d')
done
```

e.g.

```
> ./abovescript 20140226 20140303
20140226
20140227
20140228
20140301
20140302
20140303
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write a while loop using -gt and modify a variable that starts at start_date using something like:

```
$start_date=$(date -d "$start_date -1days")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $(seq 1 20); do date -v-"$i"d +%Y%m%d; done
```

Adjust 20 to however many days you want in the past. Doesn't handle your start and end date requirement exactly however, and starts with yesterday rather than an arbitrary date. May be something to get you started though.

Comment: Thanks, but the start date and end date are commandline arguments that come from another program. I would want to ideally to handle a situation like script.sh 20140226 20140303